# Creating a Gallery with GridView in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-library, android-gallery

I am trying to create a Gallery with gridview in Fragment named GalleryFrag using below code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GalleryFrag extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files;

    public GalleryFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getContext()));
        getImages();
        return view;
    }

    public void getImages() {
        File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            files = file.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                f.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return f.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                //if it's not recycled, initialize some atributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(f.get(position)));
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

But When I run the app it shows nothing in Gridview from the folder named Pictures which contains the images.
I Want to show the image in full screen when the user clicks on any image in grid view.
Can go with any different method too.
Please help me to create the gallery for my app.
Answers are really welcomed.

**CodeUpdate** 
I used this code to check file.exists :

```
public void getImages() {
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
        if (file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Yep It's there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            files = file.listFiles();
            if (files !=null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    //String[] FileNames= new String[files.length];
                    //FileNames[i]=files[i].getName();
                    //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileNames);
                    //listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    f.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**
I Need to add subfolders too in the Gallery and And need to upgrade from grid to recyclerview. I need to show images onclick on full screen but on other activities instead in same fragment with popup image viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this liabrary to import a simple gallery without need of much code:

**IMAGE GALLERY**

https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery/blob/master/README.md

**Sample Usage**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageGalleryActivity.class);

String[] images = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.unsplash_images);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList(ImageGalleryActivity.KEY_IMAGES, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(images)));
        bundle.putString(ImageGalleryActivity.KEY_TITLE, "Unsplash Images");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

**ZGallery**

https://github.com/mzelzoghbi/ZGallery

**Sample Usage**

```
ZGallery.with(this, /*your string arraylist of image urls*/)
                .setToolbarTitleColor(ZColor.WHITE) // toolbar title color
                .setGalleryBackgroundColor(ZColor.WHITE) // activity background color
                .setToolbarColorResId(R.color.colorPrimary) // toolbar color
                .setTitle("Zak Gallery") // toolbar title
                .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating adapter before save value in arraylist , So your arraylist are blank. Apply this code :-

```
public class GalleryFrag extends Fragment {
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files;

        public GalleryFrag() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
            GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv);
            getImages();
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getContext()),f);
            return view;
        }

        public void getImages() {
            File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(), "injan");
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                files = file.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    f.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
```

**Your Adapter**

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;
          ArrayList<String> f;

            public ImageAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<String> fData ) {
                mContext = context;
                f=fData ;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return f.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView imageView;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    //if it's not recycled, initialize some atributes
                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                } else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(f.get(position)));
                return imageView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying but it does not loads any images.

Answer (score 1):

> it shows nothing in Gridview from the folder in Android/Data/injan

A folder with that name/path does not exist to begin with.

> File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(), "injan");

That directory "/data/injan" would only be reachable on a rooted device. So how did you put images in it? Your arraylist does not contain elements so nothing is displayed.

> imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(f.get(position)));

Are the expected filenames numbers only? And do they equal resource identifiers? Pretty strange how this would work.

Setting the adaptor before you do the listing though is ok the way you implemented it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169531/discussion-on-answer-by-greenapps-creating-a-gallery-with-gridview-in-fragment).

Answer (score 0):

For your app to be able to read/write the file system you should request needed permissions in manifest file.

And for Android 6+ you need to add code to let the user confirm those requests at run time.

Google for runtime permissions.

You are #1254 with this problem this year.

Comment: But I did requested the permission.

Comment: In manifest maybe. That is not enough. Unclear what you are trying to tell. And why arent you reporting if you do use Android 6+ and if you added that code?

Comment: I am not using Android 6+ it's 5 lollipop. So that's why I didn't tell you.